# E486 Pattern not found : array[0]

Tags: regex, vim

I'm crafting some code related to the learn c the hard way tuto with vim now and I have an issue with the replace function:

I have made some research on Google and vim tutorial and other stackoverflow question.

But I didn't manage to find/understand an answer to my question.

I want to replace an array for pointer notation for the sake of doing it.

```
:%s/name[0]/*(name)/g
```

This command trow the following error : **E486 : Pattern not found : name[0]**.

If I do the same command without the [0] it works fine but it's not what I want to do

```
:%s/name/*(name)/g
```

How can I do the search/replace taking in account those square braquet []

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to escape the square brackets with `\`, so this'll work : `s/name\[0\]/new_name(0)/`

The reason for that is that, in most regex engine, `[]` is used to group multiple characters (see `:h /character-classes`), so `[abc]` will match either a,b or c.

Note that you could use `\M` to tell vim to use `nomagic` (usage: `s/\Mname[0]/new_name/`).

See `:h magic`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some escape sequence like `name\[0\]`. The `\` denotes that the `[` or `]` is being used as the input literal, not carrying/ denoting any special functionality [Like grouping].

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets are special in a Regular Expression: they denote a [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html). So your regex attempts to match `name0` (as there is only one character in the class).

To match literal brackets, escape them with a backslash:

```
name\[0\]
```